# WYSIWYG editor not working for IE and Microsoft Edge browers in magento 2.1 on first loading screen

Tags: wysiwyg

In IE and Microsoft browsers, the WYSIWYG editor of Magento 2.1.6 is not working when the user clicks on it after the first loading. But it is working fine on the second loading. Quick answer for this issue will be great. A screenshot for this issue is attached here. 
[image: WYSIWYG editor Issue]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick answer is don't use IE ;)